# Unable to reference jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a feeling I'm missing something obvious, could someone please help? I'm unable to reference jquery and mustache using `<script>` tags.

[404 messages](http://snag.gy/WP0Dh.jpg)

[file structure 1](http://snag.gy/1JdWS.jpg)

[file structure 2](http://snag.gy/cqTDH.jpg)

```
<script src='/js/handlebars-v3.0.1'></script>
<script src='js/handlebars-v3.0.1'></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min"></script>
<script src='http://localhost/learning/js/handlebars-v3.0.1'></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

if you notice, I'm able to read in main.js just fine using `<script src="js/main.js"></script>` but not with `<script src='js/handlebars-v3.0.1'></script>`

appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You misspelled the Javascript file names:

It should be:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/handlebars-v3.0.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Same for other Javascript files. Also, you included multiple copy of same JS.

Side note: use either double quote or single quotes only, for tidiness sake